# Function/Library like preg_match_all(PHP) in iPhone programming

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, parsing

I' m searching function that will works like preg_match_all (or similar) from for example PHP.

I want give a pattern and my NSData object(with HTML content) then get all results that fits to pattern.

I' m programming iOS 5. Is there any library or function to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Here's a snippet of code that uses it:

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *tagsRegex = [NSRegularExpression 
         regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<b>|<u>|<i>|<br/?>)" 
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                error:&error];
    if (!tagsRegex) {
        NSLog(@"Tags regex creation error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    if ([tagsRegex numberOfMatchesInString:marketingMessage options:0 
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [marketingMessage length])])
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i' m looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when i started writing iOS apps.

http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/ did helped me a lot.
But slowly i also appreciate the power os NSPredicate.

But if you – as me – like preg_match_all you need to include the regexkit (lite) in your project.

Comment: Thanks i will try it, but I read that when i will use this lib Apple could don' t agree my app to Appstore.  http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2010/07/nsregularexpression-first-step/

Comment: NSRegularExpression came later to regexkit , this what they advise you should use now (NSRegularExpression)

Comment: Regexkit has much more power then nsregularexpressions. It will be okay with all AppStore policies.