# Extract URL from download String in iOS

Tags: html, ios, json, url, nsstring

I have an iOS application which downloads and parses a JSON feed. One of the strings in the JSON feed provides a URL to an image. The problem is that it stores the URL in this format:

```
<img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/c9f50eb1fa2e16ad24e311910afabeac/tumblr_mh9v59RLTt1r5ewjho1_500.jpg"/><br/><br/><p>Vibrant Blue.</p>
```

In order to display this image in a UIImageView, I obviously only need the URL and not the HTML bit. So If I store this in a NSString, how can I then delete the rest and keep the URL in the string?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look @ this example. You can easily adopt it to your solution:

```
NSString *str = @"<img src=\"http://25.media.tumblr.com/c9f50eb1fa2e16ad24e311910afabeac/tumblr_mh9v59RLTt1r5ewjho1_500.jpg\"/><br/><br/><p>Vibrant Blue.</p>";
NSArray*arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""];
```

In this case your `arr objectAtIndex:1` is:

```
http://25.media.tumblr.com/c9f50eb1fa2e16ad24e311910afabeac/tumblr_mh9v59RLTt1r5ewjho1_500.jpg
```

Comment: How can he insert backslashes?

Comment: If he using `NSJSONSerialization` to parse this is already in this form.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. Perhaps you can do it with this.

Here's a sample code, copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217278/function-library-like-preg-match-allphp-in-iphone-programming).

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *tagsRegex = [NSRegularExpression 
         regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<b>|<u>|<i>|<br/?>)" 
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                error:&error];
if (!tagsRegex) {
    NSLog(@"Tags regex creation error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

if ([tagsRegex numberOfMatchesInString:marketingMessage options:0 
                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [marketingMessage length])])
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using `NSRegularExpression`:

```
NSString *str = @"<img src=\"http://25.media.tumblr.com/c9f50eb1fa2e16ad24e311910afabeac/tumblr_mh9v59RLTt1r5ewjho1_500.jpg\"/><br/><br/><p>Vibrant Blue.</p>";

NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\"(.*)\""
                                                                     options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                       error:NULL];
NSTextCheckingResult *result = [regexp firstMatchInString:str
                                                  options:NSMatchingReportProgress
                                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
NSString *imageURL = [str substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]]; // 1 for first capture group
```